# Installing open MPI and/or executing hello_c/ring_c fails

Tags: installation, openmpi

I am trying to install open MPI version 1.6.5 on a freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I do it as described [here](http://lsi.ugr.es/~jmantas/pdp/ayuda/datos/instalaciones/Install_OpenMPI_en.pdf) and [here](http://www.open-mpi.de/faq/?category=building). For the installation I use following commands:

1. Install C/C++ Compiler and openmpi-bin: `root#: apt-get install build-essential openmpi-bin`
2. Download and unpack: 

   `root#: wget https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v1.6/downloads/openmpi-1.6.5.tar.gz
   root#: tar -xf openmpi-1.6.5.tar.gz -C /opt
   root#: chown root:root /opt/openmpi-1.6.5`
3. Configure installation file and install it:
   `root#: cd /opt/openmpi-1.6.5
   root#: ./configure --prefix=/opt/openmpi
   root#: make all install`
4. Export Environment Variables:

   `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/openmpi/bin
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/openmpi/lib`

IMO I didn't miss any of the installation steps. But when I try to run the usual tests **on the local host** (i.e. 'zeus' in my case) i get following results:

1. `root#: mpirun hostname`
   Outputs the right hostname, in my case 'zeus'
2. `root#: mpirun hello_c`

   ```
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   mpirun was unable to launch the specified application as it could not find an executable:

   Executable: hello_c
   Node: zeus

   while attempting to start process rank 0.
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ```
3. Same for `root#: mpirun ring_c`

**What did I miss?**

Comment: Does "hello_c" exist? Did you try "mpirun ./hello_c"?

Comment: It does exist under `/opt/openmpi-1.6.5/examples/hello_c.c` . In which Folder should I run the command?

Comment: Running  `find / -iname '*hello_c*'` only outputs `/opt/openmpi-1.6.5/examples/hello_c.c` and `/opt/openmpi-1.6.5/examples/hello_cxx.cc`. Still I would like to test my system before proceeding with further installations...

Comment: You need to build hello_c executable. Try compiling it with "gcc -fopenmp hello_c.c -o hello_c". (Or, better yet, check if there's a Makefile in /opt/openmpi-1.6.5/examples/, or if there's a comment in hello_c.c that tells how to properly compile it)

Comment: YES!!! That's it! :D I entered `/opt/openmpi-1.6.5/examples` and ran `root#: make all install` and then it worked. Thank you. I definitely have to learn more about compiling ;)