# open MPI - ring_c on multiple hosts fails

Tags: testing, installation, openmpi

I have [recently installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36334388/installing-open-mpi-and-or-executing-hello-c-ring-c-fails) open MPI on two Ubuntu 14.04 hosts and I am now testing its functionality with the two provided test functions hello_c and ring_c. The hosts are called 'hermes' and 'zeus' and they both have the user 'mpiuser' to log in non-interactively (via ssh-agent).

The functions `mpirun hello_c` and `mpirun --host hermes,zeus hello_c` both work properly.

Calling the function `mpirun --host zeus ring_c` locally also works. Output for both hermes and zeus:

```
mpiuser@zeus:/opt/openmpi-1.6.5/examples$ mpirun --host zeus ring_c
Process 0 sending 10 to 0, tag 201 (1 processes in ring)
Process 0 sent to 0
Process 0 decremented value: 9
Process 0 decremented value: 8
Process 0 decremented value: 7
Process 0 decremented value: 6
Process 0 decremented value: 5
Process 0 decremented value: 4
Process 0 decremented value: 3
Process 0 decremented value: 2
Process 0 decremented value: 1
Process 0 decremented value: 0
Process 0 exiting
```

But calling the function `mpirun --host zeus,hermes ring_c` fails and gives following output:

```
mpiuser@zeus:/opt/openmpi-1.6.5/examples$ mpirun --host hermes,zeus ring_c
Process 0 sending 10 to 1, tag 201 (2 processes in ring)
[zeus:2930] *** An error occurred in MPI_Recv
[zeus:2930] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[zeus:2930] *** MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
[zeus:2930] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL: your MPI job will now abort
Process 0 sent to 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun has exited due to process rank 1 with PID 2930 on
node zeus exiting improperly. There are two reasons this could occur:

1. this process did not call "init" before exiting, but others in
the job did. This can cause a job to hang indefinitely while it waits
for all processes to call "init". By rule, if one process calls "init",
then ALL processes must call "init" prior to termination.

2. this process called "init", but exited without calling "finalize".
By rule, all processes that call "init" MUST call "finalize" prior to
exiting or it will be considered an "abnormal termination"

This may have caused other processes in the application to be
terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I haven't found any documentation on how to solve such a problem and I don't have a clue where to look for the mistake on the basis of the error output. **How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

You've changed two things between the first and second runs - you've increased the number of processes from 1 to 2, and run on multiple hosts rather than a single host.

I'd suggest you first check you can run on 2 processes on the same host:

```
mpirun -n 2 ring_c
```

and see what you get.

When debugging on a cluster it's often useful to know where each process is running. You should always print out the total number of processes as well. Try using the following code at the top of ring_c.c:

```
char nodename[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
int namelen;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

MPI_Get_processor_name(nodename, &namelen);
printf("Rank %d out of %d running on node %s\n", rank, size, nodename);
```

The error you're getting is saying that the incoming message is too large for the receive buffer, which is weird given that the code always sends and receives a single integer.

Comment: `mpirun -n 2 ring_c` on the same host works. But I guess I have found the mistake. The environment variables were not right, `ssh user@IP env` did not show me the right $PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. So I tried it with `mpirun --prefix /opt/openmpi -host hermes,zeus ring_c` and this worked. So I have to figure out what is the right way to export variables.